# WPF ComboBox IsEnabled from Items Count

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, isenabled

Im wanting the XAML of a ComboBox to handle its own IsEnabled property based on whether or not it has Items. If the DataTable in the code behind returns Items, id like the ComboBox to be enabled otherwise if no Items are added, it remains or becomes a disabled control. Is this at all possible?

My current ComboBox setup:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ImportDate" 
        DisplayMemberPath="FileDate" 
        SelectedValuePath="ID" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" 
        SelectedIndex="0" 
        Style="{DynamicResource sanComboBox_Standard}" />
```

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=OneWay` is redundant. `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the `ComboBox` to be enabled when it has items, and disabled when there are no items, you could just bind `IsEnabled` to the [HasItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.hasitems?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Controls_ItemsControl_HasItems) property:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ImportDate" 
    DisplayMemberPath="FileDate" 
    SelectedValuePath="ID" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" 
    SelectedIndex="0" 
    Style="{DynamicResource sanComboBox_Standard}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: So simple when you know how! Thanks.

Comment: Finally, someone posted how to handle this logically without behaviors and styles. Thanks.